# YouTube API v3 strange behaviour - small number of videos during searching

Tags: search, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube API v3 and during searching i found strange behaviour:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&videoCategoryId=10&fields=items(snippet(publishedAt))&key=MY_KEY&maxResults=50&type=video&order=date
```

Today was added just 2 movies in music category? Why i'm getting so small number of videos?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your request and put my_key into that (with no functional change) and send it. I got 50 (max) result. I think you have another problem

Comment: I know but look on publish date (2013-09-04) today was added just 5 videos on music category?